# Burning Snow Leopard 10.6 DMG always fails

Tags: macos, burning, dvd-burning

I'm trying to burn my `Snow Leopard 10.6`, a `6.5GB` dmg file but it always fails with [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/), I don't have toast so I would like to fine a free way, how can I do?

Can I use the disk utility directly?

I'm using a DVD+R DL 8.5GB

Comment: *What* do you actually try to burn it on? Also, what "fails"?

Comment: I've used [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I meant the medium you burn on. Are you sure it's big enough for the disk image? Also, again, what "fails"?

Comment: I'm using `TDK DVD+R 8.5GB`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just use Disk Utility.app.

1. Mount the DMG file you want to burn
2. Open Disk Utility.app
3. Click "Burn"

[image]

But this only works if:

- your burn medium is not damaged
- has the right capacity
- your Mac can write to such a medium

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and click on the  symbol in the top left menu bar. Then choose "System Profiler". Go to "Disc Burning" and see which formats are listed under "DVD-Write". If you are using a DVD+R Double Layer disk and your Mac does not support burning Double Layer disks, you're out of luck.

You can however "burn" the image onto an external HDD, an iPod or anything of that kind in order to [install Snow Leopard from USB](http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html).

Comment: The mac says the disc is not compatible with the image, so is DVD+R  not compatible?

Comment: See my updated answer above. Is "DVD+R DL" listed?

Comment: It is a DVD+R 8.5GB DL disk, I think only DVD DL disks has 8.5GB of space. Where I live the DVD-R is impossible to buy in some shop, so I made a try with DVD+R but I think it in the + my problem.

Comment: Is your Mac able to burn to DVD+R DL or not? Have you checked in System Profiler?

Comment: I've read it's not a mac problem but a DVD+R incompatibility with Leopard DMG. I must buy a DVD-R dual layer 8.5GB to burn the DMG.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't heard that yet, but you might want to try!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, to burn the `DMG` correctly with `Disk utility`, I've used `DVD-R` instead of `DVD+R`.